# Making validation on checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have multiple checkboxes, I want to show a message "You must select at least one charger" if the user clicks save without choosing one.
I have this:

[image]

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one Charger type.")]
        public IEnumerable<int> ChargerTypesIDs { get; set; }
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: You need to show your view (how your generating the checkboxes), but a `[Required]` attribute will not work on a collection. You will need to create your own validation attribute

Comment: You can try javascript or jquery for this. 1) Assign one class name to each checkbox. 2) Take count of :checked==true. if count < 1 then display alert or popup on screen. **If want to display same message as your error message use div display:hidden display div when count < 1**

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do this, the best idea would be to have a separate model class containing your checkboxes. A solution like this has been posted on codereview:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/c-multi-checkbox-validation-mvc4?newreg=210b956b94b94767aca8555bcc51fa0d

(I'm sorry if this isn't a "correct" answer, but i'm not sure how else to respond to this post)